# How to change sql into CaseBuilder?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, querydsl

This is my table.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZdZt.png)

And this is my SQL:

```sql
select t1.id
  from demo t1
 where substring(t1.id, -3) = case 
                                when (select count(*)
                                        from demo t2
                                       where t2.id like concat(substring(t1.id, 1, length(t1.id) - 3), '%')) = 2 then 'ENG'
                                else 'KOR'
                              end;
```

I tried to convert my SQL to *CaseBuilder* but no luck because it can't add the select in the `when` statement.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[After run sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEwl8.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I leave my answer here.

```
QDemo t1 = QDemo.demo;
QDemo t2 = new QDemo("t2");

BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
builder.and(t1.id.substring(-3).eq(
    new CaseBuilder()
        .when(
            JPAExpressions.select(t2.count())
                .from(t2)
                .where(t2.id.like(
                    t1.id.substring(0, t1.id.length().subtract(3)).concat("%")
                ))
                .eq(2L)
        )
        .then("ENG")
        .otherwise("KOR")
));
```